# What are some of the ways to ensure backward compatibility while making breaking API changes?

Tags: rest, api, migration

I have an internal service that exposes few APIs and few clients using these APIs. I have to make some breaking changes and redesign this service's API.

What are some of the best ways to maintain backward compatibility for these clients while making these changes? (*I known it's not ideal but most things in the world aren't, right?*)

One solution I can think of is having a config based on which the clients either talk to the old API or the new. This allows me to merge the client code immediately and then enable the new API through the config when the time is right for me.

I want to find out if there are more solutions out there that's in practice when making such breaking changes.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way is to introduce versioning in your API, e.g:

`http://api.example.com/` (can default to an older version for backwards compatibility)

`http://api.example.com/v1`

etc...

See more information and examples here: https://restfulapi.net/versioning/